# To improve performance, should I record to my C:\ or D:\ drive?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, screen-recorder

I read online that you should record to a different drive to improve performance.

- I have fraps installed to my C:\ drive, which is a 256GB SSD. It has 173 GB free. I basically install windows and non-game programs to there.
- I have my games installed to my 500GB HDD D:\ drive, which has exactly 256GB free. I basically put all my files on that drive (word files, visual studio, google drive, backups, etc)

Should I record to my SSD or HDD?

Comment: Are you currently experiencing a problem with performance ?

Comment: Yes. Normally I get around 500fps in most games but with fraps on I get around 55-ish. I know that's not bad but the fact that it's 10% of my original FPS implies it can probably be improved.

Comment: @chipperyman573 You can try unchecking the lock framerate option and see if that helps. If you're generating 500 frames a second, sure it's a nice number but it's mostly wasted anyway.

Comment: Your 128GB SSD has 173GB free?

Comment: Miswrote, 256gb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SSD will fill up **very** fast if you are recording FRAPS to it. Come to think of it, even your HDD will fill up quite fast. You'd have to record at half-resolution and 30fps or less to get more than 5 minutes at a time of video, before it gets unmanageably huge. If you plan to record hour-long shows, it just won't happen on either drive.

A few facts:

- SSD's write performance will decrease as it fills up, because an SSD is basically a large RAID array of lots of little NAND chips (think of them like SD cards without the plastic housing). A "full" chip can't participate in any write requests, so it'll just sit there. I've read sources that recommend keeping the SSD no more than 85% full to get its full write performance.
- A single 500GB 7200rpm HDD is not very likely to be able to write fast enough to keep up with the write speed of FRAPS at full resolution and FPS.
- You might be able to get under the write threshold at half resolution (which reduces the amount of data that has to be written per frame by a factor of **4**, not 2, because there are **four** times as many pixels in e.g. a 1920x1080 image as there are in a 960x540). If FRAPS still can't keep up, as evidenced by lag in the video or in your game, you can further halve the amount of data by dropping the framerate in half.

With the hardware you have, I'd recommend trying something like Bandicam to encode the video to H264 on the fly, which is the destination compression format. This will work well if you can get Intel QSV or AMD APP SDK working, but otherwise it will use too much CPU to encode on the fly. FRAPS will just use too much data, unless the duration of your planned recordings is around 5 minutes or less per recording (and then delete the FRAPS videos once you encode them offline to H264).

If you intend to do some really serious encoding (sessions of an hour or longer) I'd recommend buying two larger hard drives (1 TB or more) and putting them in RAID-0.

Comment: I'm planning on recording 5-minutes videos that I delete after I take them. I play on a GMod server with a few cheaters so I'm trying to record them cheating. I'm not uploading to youtube. Which would be better then? Also I don't really care what resolution I record at as long as my resolution is the same when I play.

Comment: Nothing you wrote in your comment changes my answer. The SSD undoubtedly has better write performance than the HDD, this is undebatable and self-evident. You will need to initiate the FRAPS captures, see how big they are, and figure out whether you can capture long enough on your SSD to get the video you want without filling up the SSD (it depends heavily on how full the SSD is already). If you're going to fill up the SSD or very nearly, it might slow it down too much, so you'll just have to try it and see.

Comment: In fact, this entire question can be answered summarily as "try it and see".

Comment: Halving the capture resolution doesn't halve the resolution you play at, by the way, so if you don't care about that aspect, you can save 75% of the storage capacity of the video by recording at half resolution.

Comment: *> A single 500GB 7200 RPM HDD* I've done it before with no problems. By my calculations (~6 GB for 5 mins @ 1080p30, meaning ~12 GB for 5 mins @ 1080p60, meaning 40 MB/s) any modern HDD, which includes the 5600 RPM ones, should be able to handle it. I've benchmarked 5600 RPM HDDs and they can manage 80+ MB/s. Of course, this is assuming minimal seeking, which means a drive with plenty of free space and little fragmentation, and you shouldn't be doing anything else with the drive *at all*. Note that this was with the default format, not the full uncompressed RGB option.

Comment: @chipperyman573 I'd say it's better for you to record an ingame demo. GMod should be able to do that. Ingame demos are pretty much a log of every action that can be played back via the game engine - and is only a couple of megabytes at most, and fairly easy to share. It's a pretty common way of reporting cheaters, at least in CS1.6.

Comment: Is that the menu that occasionally pops up when I hit Shift + F2?

Comment: @chipperyman573 You should search either Google or [gaming.se]. You could ask for more specific instructions on [gaming.se] if you want. The Goldsrc and Source engines both support this type of demo, and any game that gives you access to a console should let you record.